# DataView LIKE function on Integer value

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dataset, dataview

I have Sql table Tracks which keeps track information such as TrackID and TrackName. I have c# application with textbox and listbox. I use dataSet to retrieve sql table and when I write "3" on textbox, I want to get track names on listbox which has TrackID as "3". My code follows:

```
lbxTracks.DataSource = new DataView(das.Tables[0], "TrackID LIKE " + idNo.ToString(), "TrackName", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

But I get an error as LIKE function cannot be used on System.Int32..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know any other way to include something like `ToString()` method in a `Expression` string for `RowFilter` but this way it works:

```
lbxTracks.DataSource = new DataView(das.Tables[0], "TrackID + '' LIKE '" + idNo + "'", "TrackName", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

**NOTE** the `+ ''` this will turn your `TrackID` into `string` before performing the `LIKE`. And it works like a charm. If anyone knows another way to perform some `ToString()` on a column in the `RowFilter` string, please leave comment below. I'm really appreciated for that :)

You should use `string.Format()` to concatenate string, and notice about the use of `%` in `LIKE` expression. I think in this case you may want to use the right operator (`=` is OK for number) if you just want to compare the equality in value (not format).

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `=` operator:

```
"TrackID = "
```

That's what you really want anyway.

Comment: This in fact answers to the **specific** problem of the OP, however it doesn't answer to the general problem, for example what if the OP wants to filter for `TrackID` with an integer having format `11?22?33`, so all the values like `11122133`, `11222133`,`11322033`, ... (there are many) should be included. So the solution is somehow we have to convert the `int` to `string` and perform the LIKE on that.

Comment: @KingKing, your example is much more abstract than the OP's, and thus theoretical. I'm confident we could find a way, but as you stated, in this case we don't need to so the OP just needs to use the right operator, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Use single Quotes and '%' as

```
lbxTracks.DataSource = new DataView(das.Tables[0], 
                       "TrackID LIKE '%" + idNo + "%'", 
                       "TrackName", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Hope it Helps..

Refer

[RowFilter](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/)